# one way anova for multiple classes either matlab or python

Tags: python, matlab, for-loop, anova, t-test

i have 4 classes of size (72,22,22) and i want to do anova1 for each pair of the (22,22) in those classes .
for example; i wanna grab, let's say,  pair (2,3) in each class  and do the anova for each pair in the 4 arrays, so the output would be an array of (22,22)representing P-values of each pair across 4 classes. hopefullay my code explains what i am trying to say :)
i have tried this piece of code but im not sure cuz the results are kinda odd; i guess the issue is in 2 for loops. here is the code
here is my code :

```
x = load("plv_8_12.mat");

x = x.plv;

size(x)

ans =
        2592          22          22

S1C1 =x(1:72,:,:);

S1C2 = x(649:720,:,:);

S1C3 = x(1297:1368,:,:);

S1C4 = x(1945:2016,:,:);

p_all = [];


for x =1:22

    for y=1:22
        
        tc1 = S1C1(:,x,y);
        tc2 = S1C2(:,x,y);
        tc3 = S1C3(:,x,y);
        tc4 = S1C4(:,x,y);
        temp = [tc1 tc2 tc3 tc4];
        
        %p_all(x,y) = anova1(temp);
        [p,tbl,stats]=anova1(temp);
        
        close all
    end
end
```

Comment: Please, explain what is "classes"? What is (72,22,22) - a 3-dimentional array with such a shape? If yes, why the dimension with the size of 72 disappear?

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: classes are kinda groups ( 4 groups) 
(72,22,22) is the dimension for each group

Comment: It's confusing: does "pair (2,3)" mean one taken from "class" 2 and one from "class 3"?

Comment: Or 2 and 3 are taken along the 0-axis (which has the length of 72) in each "class"?

Comment: yes,  along the 0-axis (which has the length of 72)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the observations are structured in an array, there is a strong suspicion that they are related between each element (z, x, y) in each "class", i.e. paired. If it is the case, the regular ANOVA is a non-valid test, and one may need the repeated measures ANOVA (much slower in the code below). For the regular ANOVA, all observations need to be independent from the other group. I don't have any mat files, so I can't verify the first part of the code. If it doesn't work, please let me know.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.io as sio
from scipy.stats import f_oneway
from statsmodels.stats.anova import AnovaRM

mat_contents = sio.loadmat("plv_8_12.mat")
data = sorted(mat_contents.keys())[-1]
data = mat_contents[data]
print(data.shape)

#data = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=(2016, 22, 22))

S1C1 = data[0:72,:,:]
S1C2 = data[648:720,:,:]
S1C3 = data[1296:1368,:,:]
S1C4 = data[1944:2016,:,:]

p_all_paired = np.zeros((22,22))
p_all_indipendent = np.zeros((22,22))

for x in range(data.shape[1]):
    for y in range(data.shape[1]):
        df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': np.arange(72), 'S1C1': S1C1[:,x,y], 'S1C2': S1C2[:,x,y], 'S1C3': S1C3[:,x,y], 'S1C4': S1C4[:,x,y]}).melt(id_vars='ID', var_name='Class', value_name='Measurement')
        p_all_indipendent[x,y] = f_oneway(S1C1[:,x,y], S1C2[:,x,y], S1C3[:,x,y], S1C4[:,x,y])[1]
        p_all_paired[x,y] = AnovaRM(df, 'Measurement', 'ID', ['Class']).fit().anova_table.loc['Class','Pr > F']
        
print("Unpaired p-values")
print(p_all_indipendent)
print("\n\nPaired p-values")
print(p_all_paired)
```

Comment: thank you so much, Alex. 
the code is working perfectly.
 but the p_values are significantly different, in fact, all values are way below 0.05 
" ANOVA is a non-valid test" so what do you suggest

Comment: The repeated measures ANOVA. I added it to the code above. Moreover, it may be worth checking the sample for normality. If that assumption is violated, ANOVA is really bad.

Comment: all p-values can be below 0.05 if at least of "class" is very very different.